# Record fields assigned from different processes

Tags: vhdl

There is something strange going on when I assign different members of a record from different processes. What is the reason for this?

```
type t_collection is record
   A : std_logic;
   B : std_logic;
end record;

signal collection : t_collection ;

begin

collection.A <= '1';

process(Clk) is
begin
   if rising_edge(Clk) then
      collection.B <= '1';
   end if;
end process;
```

In the simulator, collection.A resolves to 'X', and collection.B to '1'.

Comment: Which simulator? In mine (ModelSim PE 10.2c at the moment), both elements resolve to '1'.

Comment: @fru1bat - interested in participating in VHDL standards.  See either my profile or http://www.eda.org/twiki/bin/view.cgi/P1076/WebHome

Comment: @ni9e: Maybe you constructed an example that does not reveal the real problem; if so, consider submitting the actual code.

Comment: Why use records when you can use two signals?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @fru1bat, unless there is more code in the assignment to "collection.B", it looks like you may have a bug in your simulator.

For Testbench applications, you can give the signal an initial value of all 'Z':

```
signal collection : t_collection := (A => 'Z', B => 'Z') ;
```

For RTL, I doubt the synthesis tools will like this.